# Can't hit dotnet core endpoint when publishing to docker

Tags: docker, .net-core

I've been working on this for awhile and can't seem to get a proper docker setup for my dotnet core application. It works fine when running with `dotnet run`. Here is my docker file, docker compose file, controller file, and app logs after running `docker-compose up`.

DockerFile:

```
# build application
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release

# run application
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env app/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ /app
COPY appsettings.json /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "imdb_id_retrieval.dll"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'

volumes:
  imdb_id_service_volume:
    external:
      name: imdb_id_service_volume

networks:
  app_network:
    driver: bridge

services:
  postgres_imdb_id_db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - imdb_id_service_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - app_network

  docker_imdb_id_service:
    image: docker_retrieve_data
    depends_on: 
      - "postgres_imdb_id_db"
    restart: always
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    networks:
      - app_network
    ports: 
      - "5000:80"
```

Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using imdb_data_retrieval.Logic;

namespace imdb_data_retrieval.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ImdbIdController : ControllerBase
    {
        private IRetrieveImdbIdService _retrieveImdbIdService;

        public ImdbIdController(IRetrieveImdbIdService retrieveImdbIdService){
            _retrieveImdbIdService = retrieveImdbIdService;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get(string title, string releaseYear)
        {
            var imdbId = await _retrieveImdbIdService.ScrapeImdbIdAsync(title, releaseYear);
            if (imdbId == Constants.InvalidYearResponse)
                return BadRequest(Constants.InvalidYearResponse);
            if (imdbId == null) 
                return NotFound(Constants.MovieWasNotFoundResponse);
            return Ok(imdbId);
        }
    }
}
```

So at this point I run "docker-compose build" and then "docker-compose up". This is the output:

```
[user@user-pc imdb_id_retrieval]$ docker-compose up
Starting imdb_id_retrieval_postgres_imdb_id_db_1 ... done
Recreating imdb_id_retrieval_docker_imdb_id_service_1 ... done
Attaching to imdb_id_retrieval_postgres_imdb_id_db_1, imdb_id_retrieval_docker_imdb_id_service_1
postgres_imdb_id_db_1     | 2019-05-12 12:37:58.035 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
postgres_imdb_id_db_1     | 2019-05-12 12:37:58.035 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
postgres_imdb_id_db_1     | 2019-05-12 12:37:58.112 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
postgres_imdb_id_db_1     | 2019-05-12 12:37:58.267 UTC [23] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-05-12 12:37:12 UTC
postgres_imdb_id_db_1     | 2019-05-12 12:37:58.555 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | derp
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | host=postgres_imdb_id_db; Username=postgres; Port=5432; Database=ImdbIds;
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
docker_imdb_id_service_1  |       No XML encryptor configured. Key {964dd0aa-58de-4714-b544-3c48e2b80bb9} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | Hosting environment: development
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | Content root path: /app
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | Now listening on: http://[::]:80
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Now I go to my browser and go to "http://localhost:5000/api/imdbid?title=iron%20man&releaseYear=2008" and I get a 404 response. The first time I try to hit the endpoint I see

```
docker_imdb_id_service_1  | warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
docker_imdb_id_service_1  |       Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```

And then no logs on consecutive hits. I don't think I need https configured.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

My Dockerfile now looks likes this.

```
# build application
FROM microsoft/dotnet:sdk AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./ ./
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release

# run application
FROM microsoft/dotnet:aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env app/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish/ /app
COPY appsettings.json /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5000

# changed this
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "imdb_id_retrieval.dll", "--urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Comment: By default, Kestrel monitors only requests to localhost (within the container itself). You need to use `--urls` switch to force it to listen on 0.0.0.0:5000 for example, so that external traffic can be handled. There are also other things you need to check, but mainly on virtual networking side, not your code.

Comment: So I looked into what you said and seemed to be two ways to do that. By adding the urls argument to the dotnet command or by adding .UseUrls(urls:"http://*:5000) to Program.cs. Neither of the methods worked and I'm still getting a 404 when trying to send request to the container.

Comment: you can have a look at this if it helps. https://github.com/neville-nazerane/mesg-key-store
it was a .net core project that worked with docker on linux

Comment: You could also use something like `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:5000` in your dockerfile to tell Kestrel to watch port 5000 on localhost.